# Pixel Dimensions with InDesign

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, resize

I hope to achieve a better understanding on how to provide the highest quality of images in JPEG when exporting in InDesign. The story below is a condensed version of the situation.

**Task**

My task was to create an email blast. I had set the document to 'Web,' and set the recommended size of 650px X 550px at 72 ppi in InDesign.

**Results**

Once everything was complete, I exported it to JPEG and in RGB format, and forwarded it for review. The feedback I received was that the quality/resolution was too low.

**Trial & Error**

So I went back and increased the ppi to 300 which made things much crisper. But I noticed when viewed the file info, the dimensions were much larger than the intended size. It was 2708px X 2292px. Next, I took the file into Photoshop and resized the image there. But I noticed that the quality looked a bit funky. The outlines and edges looked wavy, and not precise like it did before. But my Supervisor went forward with no additional feedback along with a larger dimension...so far.

**Afterthoughts**

So what I was doing originally was correct the whole time? I mean when I resized the larger dimension in Photoshop to the desired size, the quality is poorer than if you were exporting it from InDesign.

I'm now aware that if you want to the desired dimensions when exporting for the web with InDesign, simply keep the ppi to 72? And what confuses me is when the individual asks for a higher quality of the image, the answer was to increase the ppi from InDesign, and then resize it in Photoshop...

Comment: Yes, you were doing correct all the time. PPI has nothing to do with quality of an IMAGE it has to do with quality of display device. Well doing this in phothoshop gives you a different way to do antialasing thats all

Comment: Apparently I was just told that there's something wrong with my InDesign program...

Comment: I doubt that very much

Comment: He's going to send me a file to try to prove me wrong I guess. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: So in the end, we went with what I had originally had did, and that is exporting it in RGB at 72 PPI. Thanks for your time!